# Oauth2 on dropbox and google drive api

Tags: python, google-drive-api, dropbox

I have combined dropbox and google drive in a little app which allow yo to select a dropbox file and upload it to google drive but i have yo copy an authorization code twice every time I use this app and this is not very comfortable,how can I avoid that or get the authorization code once not every time I use it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__author__ = 'me'

import dropbox
import httplib2
import pprint
from funciones import *
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
import os
from aux import *

import requests
from StringIO import StringIO

#keys dropbox
app_key = 'mykey'
app_secret = 'mysecret'

#keys drive

CLIENT_ID = 'myid'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'mysecret'
flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)

#parte dropbox
authorize_url = flow.start()
print '1. Go to: ' + authorize_url
print '2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first)'
print '3. Copy the authorization code.'
code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
#print 'linked account: ', client.account_info()

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
#print "metadata:", folder_metadata
#print folder_metadata['contents'][0]['path']

print 'Archivos del directorio'
print '***********************'

for files in folder_metadata['contents']:
    f = files['path']
    print f[1:]

downloaded = raw_input("Introduzca el nobre del fichero que desea subir a google drive: ").strip()
f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/'+downloaded)
#print 'metadata: ', metadata['mime_type']
out = open(downloaded, 'wb')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()

#parte drive
# Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# Redirect URI for installed apps
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Path to the file to upload
FILENAME = downloaded

# Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE,
                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)


# Insert a file
media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype=metadata['mime_type'], resumable=True)
body = {
  'title': 'Subido desde dropbox',
  'description': 'A test document',
  'mimeType': metadata['mime_type']
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
pprint.pprint(file)


retrieve_all_files(drive_service)
os.remove(downloaded)
```

Answer (score 3):

The story here is different between Google and Dropbox. I'm more confident of the Dropbox side (since I work there):

- For Dropbox, once you've obtained an access token, you can keep reusing that indefinitely. So once you do `access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)`, you can save that `access_token` and reuse it any time that same user wants to use the app. (Just do `client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)` with the saved token.)
- For Google, access tokens expire after some time, so you need to use a *refresh token* to obtain a new one. So the best thing to do would be to save both (the access token and the refresh token), and reuse the access token directly if it hasn't yet expired or use the refresh token to obtain a new access token if the access token has already expired. I'm afraid I don't know Google's libraries well enough to help more with that.

Comment: Now I use `access_token, user_id = flow.finish('PMELz6idBcsAAAAAAAA.........')
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)` but i get an error `dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [400] u'invalid_grant'
`

Comment: I can only use the code once the second time I get `dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [400] u'invalid_grant`

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reuse the authorization code, which you can't do. You should reuse the *access token*, which is what's returned from `flow.finish`.

Comment: And how can I store the access token  for the next execution?

Comment: However you want? Most likely in a file, I'd say?